# Getting images from API using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting no errors in my console but all I wanted to get is the thumbnail_url which is a json in the php file. In the console it is showing that it is an array string how can I possibly access it?

**EDITS:**
 I was able to execute my desired output but the problem is that the last object was the only one being outputted in the browser.

```
<?php 
//Set API user and password
$API_USER = 'username';
$API_PASS = 'password';
//Set parameters to make cURL call to Duda
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'sampleurl');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $API_USER.':'.$API_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
//execute cURL call and get template data
$output = curl_exec($ch);
//check for errors in cURL
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
//echo $output;
print_r($output);
?>
```

here is our html and ajax request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Ajax Preview</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<script>


  $(function() {
   var $data = $('#content');
   $.ajax({
     method:'GET',
     dataType:'json',
     url:'https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/temp.json',
     success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,data){
          $data.html('<img src=' + data.thumbnail_url + '>');
      });
    }
  });
});    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also show here the array output?

Comment: you have published you API, and the API credentials.. I won't recommend that in a public post.

Comment: Those Api credentials are dummy but thanks for editing it.
Here's the php screenshot:
https://postimg.org/image/4svg44ubn/
and the html output in network.
https://postimg.org/image/b5vobivxr/

Comment: @camdev Can you change the `https` to `http` in your `url` attribute of your `$.ajax` call?

Comment: @camdev Also your `.php` which returns the `json` content seems to be ending with `]test` which makes it incorrect. Check that too.

Comment: @DavidR Cleaned some of my codes thanks for pointing that too.

Answer (score 1):

A few things are going wrong here, first off your javascript is incomplete. Both the Ajax-function and jQuery ready aren't closed properly.

```
$(function() {

var $data = $('#content');
$.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   dataType:'jsonp',
   url:'https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/default-preview-template.php',
   success: function (data) {
   $('#content').html(data)
 });
});
```

I'm no expert on PHP, maby someone else can shed some light on that part. But it seems to me a json response header is missing in the code.

Also, the $data variable is never used, you can remove it or supply it inside the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should fix your javascript closures as Remco said.

Second, it appears that your php is returning a string `test` after the json object, that way jQuery cannot convert it to a valid Javascript object. That seems to be the core issue here. As it's not anywhere on the code you sampled us i can only presume it's somewhere else on your code (which is good because it's simpler to erase) or it could have been together with the response of the curl, in this case you have to write a regex expression to remove it from it's string before printing it.

Third, you cannot input the data object directly to the html function as it is expecting an string and not an object, you should pass the `thumbnail_url` property only.

Here's a snippet of code with some modification/correction for you:

```
function() {
    var $data = $('#content');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        url:'https//www.website.com',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data[0].thumbnail_url);
        }
    });
});
```

In this code i made it use the thumbnail of the very first object from the array by using `data[0]` but you should improve your code to use the ones you need or to send from php only the one you will actually use.

---

**Important**

Not related to your issue, but you also should edit your php code to print an associative array as the outer-most array, that way you can prevent [Json Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I still stumble and don't quite get why I can't get my desired output I have tried out your code and tried to loop through it so that I can get the thumbnail url.
here are the properties

Comment: "template_name": "Italiano",
    "preview_url": "http://example.mobilewebsiteserver.com/preview/dm-theme-20012-263",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://dd-cdn.multiscreensite.com/themes-panel/preview/italiano.jpg",
    "template_id": 20012,
    "template_properties": {
and this is my forloop [link]http://jsbin.com/nuboqogeme/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You should ask another question for you other problem instead of editing this one for each different problems you may come across. The nature of your problem now is different from before. Please accept this answer if it was helpful to you and make another question with your following questions (it will get much more visibility that way). If you like, you can put a link here so we can follow you to the next question and try to solve it.